# match card game in jquery: how to keep the matched cards to not be flipped

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues finding a solution of keeping the matched cards from being flipped again. Here is a link to my JSbin: http://jsbin.com/tiroxo/1/edit

Does anyone know what needs to be added in my javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework so I'm not going to do it for you but... instead of removing the matched cards, add a class to them (jquery has an addClass method) and then when handling clicks, check whether the clicked card has this class (jquery also has a hasClass method) and ignore the click (`return;` immediately) if it does

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a few things. First if you want the cards to stay, don't remove them.  Then you could add a class using jQuery that its a match.  Then on the timer you'd need to change how it flips.  This will fill over all cards.  So you'd need to use the not selector.

Good luck.